# Custom Java Core Class

Tags: java, class, classloader

I'm interested in patching the core Java classes.
Things like datatypes as `String`, `Graphics` (Swing) and classes from `lib/rt.jar` in general.

So the way I see it, there are a couple of methods to do that:

1. create a custom classes and include them in JVM, then run the jvm with the `-Xbootclasspath`
2. write a new bootstrap loader who will instrument Java code into the custom classes
3. use agents and instrument bytecode on loading (not too familiar with this one)

I would like to hear your advice / opinions regarding the methods, maybe Im missing something out?

Comment: Advice: don't.  You'll almost certainly regret it.

Comment: sometimes "A Man's Gotta Do what A Man's Gotta Do" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Changing such classes using the boot class path could be in violation of your license agreement. (If that concerns you) Changing the byte code appears to be allowed.

Another way to change system classes is to add jars to the `jre/lib/endorsed` directory (which you have to create)  It will load anything here in preference to other jars.

Changing the String class could confuse the `-XX:UseCompressedStrings` option.  You might like to test what happens for you with any changes.

I have done this in testing to get additional analsis from the system.  I haven't tried changing these classes for production use.

I suspect whatever you are trying to do might be done another way, but without more details its impossible to say.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the license issue Peter, I wasn't aware of that.

To make a long story short , I'd like to be able to inject/instrument a custom code into ANY java class being loaded, for the purpose of monitoring,profiling and such.

I am aware of the profilers available, but I'd like to have some "behavioural" profiling (I wonder if this sentence making any sense)

Comment: Perhaps AOP is the simplest approach. This does the byte code injection for you.  It allows you to inject code when methods are entered/exited. e.g. to log such events.

Comment: OK, Sounds good. I will have a look into that, if you have any recommended place I can start with (instead of deep diving into AOP) that would be great!


But can I achieve this kind of behaviour through **Agents**?

Comment: You can, but byte code manipulation is a tricky business.  Using AOP you can write something which looks like Java. AOP can provide an agent for runtime byte code injection. Here are some frameworks http://www.java-sources.net/open-source/aspect-oriented-frameworks

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to download / checkout the OpenJDK source code and build it for yourself with your modifications included.

But don't call it Java.  What you are doing most likely will cause it to be incompatible with the real thing.

> sometimes "A Man's Gotta Do what A Man's Gotta Do" ;)

Quoting John Wayne doesn't make what you are proposing a wise move.

---

> no , no , no. I want it to be compatible with HotSpot.

Compatibility with HotSpot is not sufficient. There are strict rules governing the use of the Java trademark on a "java" implementation.  You are only allowed to call your implementation Java if it *has passed* the Java STK tests.

And "I want it to be compatible" means something different to "is compatible", and that's ignoring the question of what you mean by compatible.

Comment: no , no , no. I want it to be compatible with HotSpot, that's why was asking about Agents.

if you have any *constructional* suggestions that can fit my need , I would be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: @PavelK - if you care to read my answer properly, you will see that it **is** a constructive answer.  Hint: first sentence.